# Discord py TypeError: command_name_error() missing 1 required positional argument: 'error'

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, bots

So, I have been working on a cog that attaches to my main.py file. The cog holds a !enter command along with a !start (command) function and !stop (command) function, which enables & disables the enter command from being used. The enter command takes the usernames of those that do !enter and puts them into a text file. However, whenever I start the bot and do !enter, everything works fine and it records the entry. After doing !enter, I do !stop entry and it disables the command !enter. But when I do !start entry to re-enable the command and type !enter, I get the error:

```
raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: command_name_error() missing 1 required positional argument: 'error'
```

(error also populates if I try to do !enter after disabling the command as well. But it's like it won't re-enable and it populates the above error when I do !enter.)

This error is driving me bonkers and I can't find out why it's populating.

My code is below.

```
# COG CLASS
class Entries(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

# START UP
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Entry.py is connected.')

# ENTER COMMAND
    @commands.command(name="entry", aliases=["enter","Enter","ENTER"])
    @commands.cooldown(1, 180, commands.BucketType.user)
    async def entry(self, ctx):
        filename = "entries.txt"
        with open(filename, "a") as file: 
            file.write(f"{ctx.author.name}\n")
            await ctx.send(f"**@{ctx.author.name} Your entry has been recorded. :white_check_mark:**")

    @entry.error
    async def command_name_error(self, ctx, error):
        if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
            await ctx.send(f"**@{ctx.author.name} You have already entered! :warning:**")

# STOP COMMAND
    @commands.command()
    async def stop(self, ctx, *, command):
        command = self.client.get_command(command)
        command.update(enabled=False)
        await ctx.author.send(f" The command **!enter** has been **disabled**.")
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)

# START COMMAND
    @commands.command()
    async def start(self, ctx, *, command):
        command = self.client.get_command(command)
        command.update(enabled=True)
        await ctx.author.send(f" The command **!enter** has been **enabled**.")
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Entries(client))
```

FULL ERROR CODE

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nitro\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Nitro\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 855, in invoke
    await self.prepare(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Nitro\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 789, in prepare
    await self._parse_arguments(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Nitro\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 697, in _parse_arguments
    transformed = await self.transform(ctx, param)
  File "C:\Users\Nitro\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 542, in transform
    raise MissingRequiredArgument(param)
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: ctx is a required argument that is missing.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nitro\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 71, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: command_name_error() missing 1 required positional argument: 'error'
    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Nitro\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\client.py", 
    line 343, in _run_event
        await coro(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\Nitro\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 979, in on_message
        await self.process_commands(message)
      File "C:\Users\Nitro\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 976, in process_commands
        await self.invoke(ctx)
      File "C:\Users\Nitro\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 943, in invoke
        await ctx.command.dispatch_error(ctx, exc)
      File "C:\Users\Nitro\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 424, in dispatch_error
        await injected(ctx, error)
      File "C:\Users\Nitro\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 77, in wrapped
        raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
    discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: command_name_error() missing 1 required positional argument: 'error'
```

Comment: There is more from the traceback - note the first line _The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception_

Comment: this problem seems to stem from wherever you have the `on_message()` event listener you need to share the code for that